# Not recovering from an f5 drop during spock test

Tags: httpclient, spock, f5

Has anyone ever created a successful Spock test against an f5 dropped connection?

In my f5 rule, if a situation is satisfied - say a bad cookie, I drop the connection

```
if { [HTTP::cookie exists "badCookie"] } {
  if { not ([HTTP::cookie "badCookie"] matches_regex {^([A-Z0-9_\s]+)$}) } {
    drop
  }
}
```

Testing this manually, in a browser, results in a slow but eventual timeout, time limit depending on the browser.  But rather than manual tests for each of the f5 rules, I'd like to instead incorporate my tests into our Spock functional test library.

Using Spock, @Timeout() or @Timeout(value=5) just ends up doing a never ending increase in the timeout like:

```
[spock.lang.Timeout] Method 'abc' has not yet returned - interrupting. Next try in 0.50 seconds.
[spock.lang.Timeout] Method 'abc' has not yet returned - interrupting. Next try in 1.00 seconds.
[spock.lang.Timeout] Method 'abc' has not yet returned - interrupting. Next try in 2.00 seconds.
[spock.lang.Timeout] Method 'abc' has not yet returned - interrupting. Next try in 4.00 seconds.
[spock.lang.Timeout] Method 'abc' has not yet returned - interrupting. Next try in 8.00 seconds.
[spock.lang.Timeout] Method 'abc' has not yet returned - interrupting. Next try in 16.00 seconds.
```

Using the waitFor method approach in http://fbflex.wordpress.com/2010/08/25/geb-and-grails-tips-tricks-and-gotchas/ or https://github.com/hexacta/weet/blob/master/weet/src/groovy/com/hexacta/weet/pages/AjaxPage.groovy does not close out the method using a 5 second specification either.

An example of the code using each of those approaches (timeout class, timeout method, and waitFor) is at https://gist.github.com/ledlogic/b152370b95e971b3992f

My question is has anyone found a way to successfully run a Spock test to verify f5 rules are dropping connections?

Comment: Did you by any chance found a solution to this in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

For me using the `@ThreadInterrupt` annotation alongside the `@Timeout` annotation worked:

```
@ThreadInterrupt
@Timeout(value = 100, unit = MILLISECONDS)
def 'timeout test'() {
    expect:
    while(1) {true}
}
```

You'll find the full documentation here: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/#GroovyConsole-Interrupt

> However, this may not be sufficient to interrupt a script: clicking
>   the button will interrupt the execution thread, but if your code
>   doesn’t handle the interrupt flag, the script is likely to keep
>   running without you being able to effectively stop it. To avoid that,
>   you have to make sure that the Script > Allow interruption menu item
>   is flagged. This will automatically apply an AST transformation to
>   your script which will take care of checking the interrupt flag
>   (@ThreadInterrupt). This way, you guarantee that the script can be
>   interrupted even if you don’t explicitly handle interruption, at the
>   cost of extra execution time.